# How to check in workbook sheet exist or not using JXL in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jxl

I want to check that in workbook it contain sheet name "Login" or not.
If it exist then in these I want to write data row=row+1, else write directly and then close the report.
So, can anybody let me know how to do it. I want to do it in below method.

**Main Class:**

```
public class MainClass {
    private static final String BROWSER_PATH = "D:\\softs\\FF installed\\FF18\\firefox.exe";
    private static final String TEST_SUITE_PATH = "D:\\softs\\configuration\\GmailTestSuite.xls";
    private static final String TEST_RESULT = "D:\\softs\\configuration\\TestResult.xls";
    private static final String OBJECT_REPOSITORY_PATH = "D:\\softs\\configuration\\objectrepository.xls";
    private static final String ADDRESS_TO_TEST = "https://www.gmail.com";

    // other constants

    private WebDriver driver;
    private Properties properties;

    /* private WebElement we; */

    public MainClass() {
        File file = new File(BROWSER_PATH);
        FirefoxBinary fb = new FirefoxBinary(file);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(fb, new FirefoxProfile());
        driver.get(ADDRESS_TO_TEST);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MainClass main = new MainClass();

        main.handleTestSuite();
    }

    private void handleTestSuite() throws Exception {
        ReadPropertyFile readConfigFile = new ReadPropertyFile();
        properties = readConfigFile.loadPropertiess();

        ExcelHandler testSuite = new ExcelHandler(TEST_SUITE_PATH, "Suite");
        testSuite.columnData();

        int rowCount = testSuite.rowCount();
        System.out.println("Total Rows=" + rowCount);

        for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
            String executable = testSuite.readCell(
                    testSuite.getCell("Executable"), i);
            System.out.println("Executable=" + executable);

            if (executable.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                // exe. the process
                String scenarioName = testSuite.readCell(
                        testSuite.getCell("TestScenario"), i);
                System.out.println("Scenario Name=" + scenarioName);
                handleScenario(scenarioName);
            }

        }

    }

    private void handleScenario(String scenarioName) throws Exception {
        ExcelHandler testScenarios = new ExcelHandler(TEST_SUITE_PATH);
        testScenarios.setSheetName(scenarioName);
        testScenarios.columnData();
        int rowWorkBook1 = testScenarios.rowCount();
        for (int j = 1; j < rowWorkBook1; j++) {
            String sno = testScenarios.readCell(
                    testScenarios.getCell("Sno"), j); // SendKey
            String testCaseDescription = testScenarios.readCell(
                    testScenarios.getCell("TestCaseDescription"), j);

            String framWork = testScenarios.readCell(
                    testScenarios.getCell("FrameworkName"), j);
            String operation = testScenarios.readCell(
                    testScenarios.getCell("Operation"), j); // SendKey
            String value = testScenarios.readCell(
                    testScenarios.getCell("Value"), j);
            System.out.println("FRMNameKK=" + framWork + ",Operation="
                    + operation + ",Value=" + value);

//          handleObjects(operation, value, framWork);
            boolean bTestCaseStepStatus = handleObjects(operation, value, framWork);

            generateReport(bTestCaseStepStatus,scenarioName,sno,testCaseDescription);

            //Report
        }
    }

    private void generateReport(boolean bTestCaseStepStatus, String testSuiteName, String SNO, String testCaseDescription) 
    throws RowsExceededException, WriteException, IOException
    {
        //String testReportPath = "D://Chayan//TestExecution.xls";
        WritableData writableData= new WritableData(TEST_RESULT, testSuiteName);

        //If sheet name is already exist then .... write data at row = row +1 
        //else write directly .. means row = 1


        System.out.println("WRITABLEDATA>>><<<<>>><<>>"+writableData);
            writableData.shSheet("Login", 5, 1, "Pass");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            //writableData.shSheet("Login", 5, 2, "Fail");
            //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
           // writableData.shSheet("Login", 5, 3, "N/A");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


        //Finally .... close the Report file ...    
    }

    private boolean handleObjects(String operation, String value, String framWork)
            throws Exception {
        //Return true / False
        System.out.println("HandleObject--> " + framWork);
        ExcelHandler objectRepository = new ExcelHandler(
                OBJECT_REPOSITORY_PATH, "OR");
        objectRepository.columnData();
        int rowCount = objectRepository.rowCount();
        System.out.println("Total Rows in hadleObject=" + rowCount);
        boolean testStepStatus = false;

        for (int k = 1; k < rowCount; k++) {
            String frameWorkName = objectRepository.readCell(
                    objectRepository.getCell("FrameworkName"), k);
            String ObjectName = objectRepository.readCell(
                    objectRepository.getCell("ObjectName"), k);
            String Locator = objectRepository.readCell(
                    objectRepository.getCell("Locator"), k); // SendKey

            System.out.println("FrameWorkNameV=" + frameWorkName
                    + ",ObjectName=" + ObjectName + ",Locator=" + Locator);

            if (framWork.equalsIgnoreCase(frameWorkName)) {
                testStepStatus = operateWebDriver(operation, Locator, value, ObjectName);

            }
        }

        return testStepStatus;
    }

    private boolean operateWebDriver(String operation, String Locator,
            String value, String objectName) throws Exception 
    {
        boolean testCaseStep = false;

        try {
            System.out.println("Operation execution in progress");
            WebElement temp = getElement(Locator, objectName);
            if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("SendKey")) {
                temp.sendKeys(value);
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Click")) {
                temp.click();
            }
            if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Verify")) {
                System.out.println("Verify--->" + temp);
                temp.isDisplayed();

            }

            testCaseStep = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred operateWebDriver"+ e.getMessage());
        }

        return testCaseStep;
    }

    public WebElement getElement(String locator, String objectName)
            throws Exception {
        WebElement temp = null;
        System.out.println("Locator-->" + locator);
        if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.id(objectName));

        } else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath(objectName));
            System.out.println("xpath temp ----->" + temp);
        } else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.name(objectName));
        }
        return temp;


    }

}
```

**WritablData Class:**

```
public class WritableData {

    Workbook wbook;
    WritableWorkbook wwbCopy;
    String ExecutedTestCasesSheet;
    WritableSheet shSheet;

    public WritableData(String testSuitePath, String OBJECT_REPOSITORY_PATH) throws RowsExceededException, WriteException 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub


         try { 
         wbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(testSuitePath)); 
         wwbCopy= Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(testSuitePath),wbook);
         System.out.println("writable workbookC-->" +wwbCopy);
         shSheet=wwbCopy.getSheet("Login");
         System.out.println("writable sheetC-->" +shSheet); 
          //shSheet = wwbCopy.createSheet("Login", 1); 
         } catch (Exception e) { 
             // TODO: handle exception 
             System.out.println("Exception message" + e.getMessage()); e.printStackTrace(); } 
    }

          public void shSheet(String strSheetName, int iColumnNumber, int
          iRowNumber, String strData) throws WriteException, IOException { 
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        System.out.println("strDataCC---->>" +strData);
        System.out.println("strSheetName<<>><<>><<>>" +strSheetName);

          WritableSheet wshTemp = wwbCopy.getSheet(strSheetName);
          //shSheet=wwbCopy.getSheet("Login"); 
          shSheet=wwbCopy.getSheet(strSheetName);

          //String a[][] = new String[shSheet.getRows()][shSheet.getColumns()];

         WritableFont cellFont = null;
          WritableCellFormat cellFormat = null;

          if (strData.equalsIgnoreCase("PASS")) { 
          cellFont = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 12);
          cellFont.setColour(Colour.GREEN);
          cellFont.setBoldStyle(WritableFont.BOLD);

          cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(cellFont);
          cellFormat.setBorder(Border.ALL, BorderLineStyle.THIN); }

          else if (strData.equalsIgnoreCase("FAIL")) { 
          cellFont = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 12); 
          cellFont.setColour(Colour.RED);
          cellFont.setBoldStyle(WritableFont.BOLD);

          cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(cellFont);
          cellFormat.setBorder(Border.ALL, BorderLineStyle.THIN); }

          else { cellFont = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 12);
          cellFont.setColour(Colour.BLACK);
          cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(cellFont);
          cellFormat.setBorder(Border.ALL, BorderLineStyle.THIN);
          cellFormat.setWrap(true); }


          Label labTemp = new Label(iColumnNumber, iRowNumber, strData,
          cellFormat);
          shSheet.addCell(labTemp); 
          System.out.println("writableSheet---->"+shSheet);

          wwbCopy.write(); 
          wwbCopy.close();
          wbook.close();
}
}
```

Comment: tutorial from andykhan should suffice http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html

Comment: @Kavan I've already checked that , can you please let me know the exact way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not get the answer of my question here but yeah now I got the solution and its work fine for me, please check the below code hope it will help you also:

```
public class MainClass {
    private static final String BROWSER_PATH = "D:\\softs\\FF installed\\FF18\\firefox.exe";
    private static final String TEST_SUITE_PATH = "D:\\softs\\configuration\\GmailTestSuite.xls";
    private static final String TEST_RESULT = "D:\\softs\\configuration\\TestResult.xls";
    private static final String OBJECT_REPOSITORY_PATH = "D:\\softs\\configuration\\objectrepository.xls";
    private static final String ADDRESS_TO_TEST = "https://www.gmail.com";

    // other constants

    private WebDriver driver;
    private Properties properties;

    /* private WebElement we; */

    public MainClass() {
        File file = new File(BROWSER_PATH);
        FirefoxBinary fb = new FirefoxBinary(file);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(fb, new FirefoxProfile());
        driver.get(ADDRESS_TO_TEST);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MainClass main = new MainClass();
        main.handleTestSuite();
    }

    private void handleTestSuite() throws Exception {
        ReadPropertyFile readConfigFile = new ReadPropertyFile();
        properties = readConfigFile.loadPropertiess();

        ExcelHandler testSuite = new ExcelHandler(TEST_SUITE_PATH, "Suite");
        testSuite.columnData();

        int rowCount = testSuite.rowCount();
        System.out.println("Total Rows=" + rowCount);

        for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
            String executable = testSuite.readCell(
                    testSuite.getCell("Executable"), i);
            System.out.println("Executable=" + executable);

            if (executable.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                // exe. the process
                String scenarioName = testSuite.readCell(
                        testSuite.getCell("TestScenario"), i);
                System.out.println("Scenario Name=" + scenarioName);
                handleScenario(scenarioName);
            }

        }

    }

    private void handleScenario(String scenarioName) throws Exception {
        ExcelHandler testScenarios = new ExcelHandler(TEST_SUITE_PATH);
        testScenarios.setSheetName(scenarioName);
        testScenarios.columnData();
        int rowWorkBook1 = testScenarios.rowCount();
        for (int j = 1; j < rowWorkBook1; j++) {
            String sno = testScenarios.readCell(
                    testScenarios.getCell("Sno"), j); // SendKey
            String testCaseDescription = testScenarios.readCell(
                    testScenarios.getCell("TestCaseDescription"), j);

            String framWork = testScenarios.readCell(
                    testScenarios.getCell("FrameworkName"), j);
            String operation = testScenarios.readCell(
                    testScenarios.getCell("Operation"), j); // SendKey
            String value = testScenarios.readCell(
                    testScenarios.getCell("Value"), j);
            System.out.println("FRMNameKK=" + framWork + ",Operation="
                    + operation + ",Value=" + value);

            boolean bTestCaseStepStatus = handleObjects(operation, value, framWork);
                    generateReport(bTestCaseStepStatus,scenarioName,sno,testCaseDescription,j);
            }
    }

    private boolean generateReport(boolean bTestCaseStepStatus, String testSuiteName, String SNO, String testCaseDescription, int j) 
    throws RowsExceededException, WriteException, IOException
    {
        WritableData writableData= new WritableData(TEST_RESULT, testSuiteName);

        if(bTestCaseStepStatus){
            writableData.shSheet("Login", 2, j, "Pass");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }else{
            writableData.shSheet("Login", 2, j, "Fail");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

        return bTestCaseStepStatus;

    }

    private boolean handleObjects(String operation, String value, String framWork)
            throws Exception {
        //Return true / False
        System.out.println("HandleObject--> " + framWork);
        ExcelHandler objectRepository = new ExcelHandler(
                OBJECT_REPOSITORY_PATH, "OR");
        objectRepository.columnData();
        int rowCount = objectRepository.rowCount();
        System.out.println("Total Rows in hadleObject=" + rowCount);
        boolean testStepStatus = false;

        for (int k = 1; k < rowCount; k++) {
            String frameWorkName = objectRepository.readCell(
                    objectRepository.getCell("FrameworkName"), k);
            String ObjectName = objectRepository.readCell(
                    objectRepository.getCell("ObjectName"), k);
            String Locator = objectRepository.readCell(
                    objectRepository.getCell("Locator"), k); // SendKey

            System.out.println("FrameWorkNameV=" + frameWorkName
                    + ",ObjectName=" + ObjectName + ",Locator=" + Locator);

            if (framWork.equalsIgnoreCase(frameWorkName)) {
                testStepStatus = operateWebDriver(operation, Locator, value, ObjectName);

            }
        }

        return testStepStatus;
    }

    private boolean operateWebDriver(String operation, String Locator,
            String value, String objectName) throws Exception 
    {
        boolean testCaseStep = false;

        try {
            System.out.println("Operation execution in progress");
            WebElement temp = getElement(Locator, objectName);
            if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("SendKey")) {
                temp.sendKeys(value);
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Click")) {
                temp.click();
            }
            if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Verify")) {
                System.out.println("Verify--->" + temp);
                temp.isDisplayed();

            }

            testCaseStep = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred operateWebDriver"+ e.getMessage());
        }

        return testCaseStep;
    }

    public WebElement getElement(String locator, String objectName)
            throws Exception {
        WebElement temp = null;
        System.out.println("Locator-->" + locator);
        if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.id(objectName));

        } else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath(objectName));
            System.out.println("xpath temp ----->" + temp);
        } else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.name(objectName));
        }
        return temp;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Strategy** :

workbookobj.getNumberOfSheets()---->Get the no of sheets in the workbook

use a for loop and iterate through all sheets in the workbook

workbookobj.getSheet(sheetno).getName()---->returns the sheet name compare it with the login string to check if the sheetname is equal to login.

```
 for(int i=0;i<workbookobj.getNumberOfSheets();i++){

    if(workbookobj.getSheet(i).getName().contentEquals("login")){

    //use  Writeableworkbookobj.getSheet(); to return the specific sheet and write the data into the sheet                                                                          

    }else {

                    //do your stuff
    }
                }
```

**EDITED** :

```
    private void generateReport(boolean bTestCaseStepStatus, String testSuiteName, String SNO, String testCaseDescription) 
        throws RowsExceededException, WriteException, IOException
        {

            //Here create an workbook object

             Workbook workbookobj =  Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(TEST_RESULT));

               WritableData writableData= new WritableData(TEST_RESULT, testSuiteName);

                for(int i=0;i<workbookobj.getNumberOfSheets();i++){

                   if(workbookobj.getSheet(i).getName().contentEquals("login")){

                 if(bTestCaseStepStatus){

                  writableData.shSheet("Login", 2, j, "Pass");
                    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }else{
                  writableData.shSheet("Login", 2, j, "Fail");
                   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }                                  

        }else {
                   //use your writable object to write directly into any sheet

             if(bTestCaseStepStatus){

                  writableData.shSheet(/*write data into any other sheet*/);
                    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }else{
                  writableData.shSheet(/*write data into any other sheet*/);
                   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }            

        }
                    }
```

Hope this helps you....

Comment: I want to apply this login on main class, so can you please check the update code and let me know that in generateReport method how can I do the same problem?

Comment: I have edited my above post....i hope it will help you...Kindly get back if you have any queries

Comment: As in code you can see that I've comment the line "String testReportPath = "D://Chayan//TestExecution.xls";". The sheet in which I have to write is "TEST_RESULT" as you can see on next line. So, kindly let me know the code accordingly. Also as you want to see the "WritableData class" logic I've posted it. Kindly check and revert me.

Comment: When I am following your editing code it gives me Null pointer exception. 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at jxl.write.biff.File.write(File.java:149)
at jxl.write.biff.WritableWorkbookImpl.write(WritableWorkbookImpl.java:706)
at com.af.WritableData.shSheet(WritableData.java:102)
at com.af.MainClass.generateReport(MainClass.java:139)
at com.af.MainClass.handleScenario(MainClass.java:106)
at com.af.MainClass.handleTestSuite(MainClass.java:82)
at com.af.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:61)