# How to read multiple sheet in continution from one workbook using java?

Tags: java, excel, jexcelapi

I have an multiple sheets in one workbook, it read each and every rows too.

But each time it start reading the sheet from first row and because of that when it start to set/writing the status of cases, it again start to set the result from first row means it overlap the result of each cases on same row.

Also, for reading and writing sheet I am using Jxl api.

**Below are the code for logic can anyone please let me know how to resolved it:**

```
    private void handleScenario(String scenarioName) throws Exception {
        ExcelHandler testScenarios = new ExcelHandler(TEST_SUITE_PATH);
        testScenarios.setSheetName(scenarioName);
        testScenarios.columnData();    

        int rowWorkBook1 = testScenarios.rowCount();
        System.out.println("Total Rows1: "+ rowWorkBook1);

        for (int j = 1; j < rowWorkBook1; j++) {
            String sno = testScenarios.readCell(testScenarios.getCell("Sno"), j); // SendKey
            String testCaseDescription = testScenarios.readCell(testScenarios.getCell("TestCaseDescription"), j);
            String framWork = testScenarios.readCell(testScenarios.getCell("FrameworkName"), j);
            String operation = testScenarios.readCell(testScenarios.getCell("Operation"), j); // SendKey
            String value = testScenarios.readCell(testScenarios.getCell("Value"), j);

            handleObjects(operation, value, framWork);
            boolean bTestCaseStepStatus = handleObjects(operation,value, framWork);

            generateReport(bTestCaseStepStatus, scenarioName, sno,testCaseDescription, j);
        }
    }

private boolean generateReport(boolean bTestCaseStepStatus,
            String testSuiteName, String SNO, String testCaseDescription, int j)
            throws RowsExceededException, WriteException, IOException {

        WritableData writableData = new WritableData(TEST_RESULT, testSuiteName, j, 2);

        // If sheet name is already exist then .... write data at row = row +1
        // else write directly .. means row = 1

        if (bTestCaseStepStatus) {
            //System.out.println("--------------"+bTestCaseStepStatus+"------------");
            System.out.println("SNo=" +SNO+ ",Test description=" + testCaseDescription + "Row ID: " + j);

            writableData.shSheet("Result", 2, j, "Pass");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } else {
        //  System.out.println("--------------"+bTestCaseStepStatus+"------------");    
            System.out.println("SNo=" +SNO+ ",Test description=" + testCaseDescription + "Row ID: "+ j);            

            writableData.shSheet("Result", 2, j, "Fail");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

        return bTestCaseStepStatus;

        // Finally .... close Report file ... 
    }

    private boolean handleObjects(String operation, String value,
            String framWork) throws Exception {
        // Return true / False
        ExcelHandler objectRepository = new ExcelHandler(OBJECT_REPOSITORY_PATH, "OR");
        objectRepository.columnData();
        int rowCount = objectRepository.rowCount();
        //System.out.println("Total Rows in hadleObject=" + rowCount);
        boolean testStepStatus = false;

        for (int k = 1; k < rowCount; k++) {
            String frameWorkName = objectRepository.readCell(
                    objectRepository.getCell("FrameworkName"), k);
            String ObjectName = objectRepository.readCell(
                    objectRepository.getCell("ObjectName"), k);
            String Locator = objectRepository.readCell(
                    objectRepository.getCell("Locator"), k); // SendKey

            //System.out.println("FrameWorkNameV=" + frameWorkName
            //      + ",ObjectName=" + ObjectName + ",Locator=" + Locator);

            if (framWork.equalsIgnoreCase(frameWorkName)) {
                testStepStatus = operateWebDriver(operation, Locator, value,
                        ObjectName);

            }
        }

        return testStepStatus;
    }
```

Comment: Your method handleObjects() is called twice - is that intentional?
Also, it seems like all you do is read values in this part of your code, could you post your handleObjects() and generateReport() methods?

Comment: @UlliSchmid I have posted handleObjects() and generateReport() methods both please check.

Comment: Thanks for that. Again - handleObjects(operation, value, framWork); is called 2 times - intentional? Maybe try commenting out line 16?

Comment: I feel like I understand what your code is attempting to do, but could you please elaborate on the problem - what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: @UlliSchmid Already written above, can you please check that?

Comment: That sentence is hard to understand :/

Comment: @UlliSchmid In simple way, the sheet in which my status is set in that each time it start to set the result from first row.. so it overlape over my previous results.

Answer (score 0):

You have not implemented what your comment in generateReport() refers to:

```
// If sheet name is already exist then .... write data at row = row +1
// else write directly .. means row = 1
```

Please change it to:

```
ExcelHandler countRowsHandler = new ExcelHandler(TEST_RESULT);
countRowsHandler.setSheetName(testSuiteName);
countRowsHandler.columnData();
int existingRowCount= countRowsHandler.rowCount();
j = j + existingRowCount
```

**Explanation:**

I deduced this from the documentation you have provided here:

[How to check in workbook sheet exist or not using JXL in selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442208/how-to-check-in-workbook-sheet-exist-or-not-using-jxl-in-selenium-webdriver)

```
WritableData.shSheet(String strSheetName, int iColumnNumber, int iRowNumber, String strData)
```

accepts a row number, as third argument. In

```
writableData.shSheet("Result", 2, j, "Pass");
writableData.shSheet("Result", 2, j, "Fail");
```

you provide j, which is a "Row ID". This j comes from

```
for (int j = 1; j < rowWorkBook1; j++) {
```

so it will always start at 1 for every new call of handleScenario(), overwriting previous runs. You need to find out how many rows there already are. Judging from your code (there is no reference to this method documented on the Internet), you can do this with an ExcelHandler and .rowCount()

Please consider refactoring and cleaning up this entire codebase, it is quite a mess. Using outdated libraries (jxl), strange variable naming and comments will make it hell for any outsider to understand what is happening here.

Comment: I have already used this line 
ExcelHandler countRowsHandler = new ExcelHandler(TEST_RESULT);
countRowsHandler.setSheetName(testSuiteName);
countRowsHandler.columnData();
int existingRowCount= countRowsHandler.rowCount();
j = j + existingRowCount
in handleScenario() method.

Comment: Please follow my instructions, they are very extensive.

Comment: can you please share the solution of code integration according to current code scenario please?

Comment: Your code and question are very hard to understand. Despite that, I have spent a lot of time trying to help you. Downvoting my quite extensive answer is both rude and counterproductive. Good luck in your future endeavours, next time I will not help you.

Comment: First of all its easy to understand how my code is work because you get the other classes too. So, don't tell that its hard to understand. Second the way you told it changes my who code structure and its not reading my sheet "Test_Result". Third I got the solution and that is solved by writing only three lines instead of doing this much of changes. If you have time just check it and it works fine for me. Also I am not being rude by giving down-voting its just because that its not worth for me to doing lots of changes in my code.

Comment: Difficult not because of the size, but because of how poorly it was written. My solution requires only one change.

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution by writing 3 lines and below they are:

1. Declare public int rowNumber=0;
2. See the below handleScenario() method:

   private void handleScenario(String scenarioName) throws Exception {

   ```
       ExcelHandler testScenarios = new ExcelHandler(TEST_SUITE_PATH);
       testScenarios.setSheetName(scenarioName);
       testScenarios.columnData();
       int rowWorkBook1 = testScenarios.rowCount();
       System.out.println("Total Rows1: "+ rowWorkBook1);

       for (int j = 1; j < rowWorkBook1; j++) {
           String sno = testScenarios
                   .readCell(testScenarios.getCell("Sno"), j); // SendKey
           String testCaseDescription = testScenarios.readCell(
                   testScenarios.getCell("TestCaseDescription"), j);

           String framWork = testScenarios.readCell(
                   testScenarios.getCell("FrameworkName"), j);
           String operation = testScenarios.readCell(
                   testScenarios.getCell("Operation"), j); // SendKey
           String value = testScenarios.readCell(
                   testScenarios.getCell("Value"), j);
                       boolean bTestCaseStepStatus = handleObjects(operation, value,
                   framWork);
           generateReport(bTestCaseStepStatus, scenarioName, sno,
                   testCaseDescription, j+rowNumber);

           // Report
       }
        rowNumber = rowWorkBook1;
   }
   ```

Comment: This is an alternative to my answer.  It will only work for a maximum of two "Scenarios". Starting with a third Scenario, you will start overwriting your previous entries again. Change this to rowNumber = rowNumber + rowWorkBook1.

Comment: @UlliSchmid Your this solution is also not work whenever it switch to another sheet(In same workbook) it set the result properly. 

But in test-result workbook it escape one row between two different sheets cases.